# How to load the user contol from another project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using User Controls from Other Projects in ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709617/using-user-controls-from-other-projects-in-asp)

I have the following case: A solution has two projects, A and B. One of them, A, has a `UserControl`.

Now I build A and add a reference to A in B. How is it possible to load the user control in B and access the controls in that user control?

I want to avoid to rebuild Project `B` every time i change one of the user controls ?

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640516/how-to-make-usercontrol-available-to-multiple-projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use to proceed like this, working with IIS, ASP.NET 4.0 :

1. Place the control myControl.ascx I want A to share in a subfolder of Application A  named *SharedControls*
2. in IIS, add a virtual directory (no app, but with execute script rights) to B, 'ASharedControls', pointing on A's *SharedControls* (referencing this subdirectory, you will avoid B including A's web.config in it's hierachy, which would make B crash)
3. In B, add a project reference to A
4. In B, you can now declare and use your control in markup with 
   `<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="myControl" Src="~/ASharedControls/myControl.ascx" %>` (VS will warn as path not found, but it should work in IIS)
5. myControl should then be also available in codebehind for B's pages and controls

Depending on your pages and controls being codefile/codebehind, you might have to set batch="false" in web.config compilation element, to avoid multi-compilation conflicts :

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" batch="false" targetFramework="4.0">
```

Hope this will help