# Splitting ASP.NET application in two applications - handling of shared pages / user controls / scripts

Tags: asp.net, svn, split, linked-list

I have a big ASP.NET application (legacy) which actually (functionally) is composed from two portals. So I need to split it to two separate applications, to ease the development on each of them.

Of course there are shared features between the two. Some of them are in DAL and BL, and that is not an issue - all that code was separate din separate projects, which made up assemblies that are to be referenced in both apps.

But the problem is with some pages, lot of user controls, some css and javascript files, which are shared between the two "portals" (applications).

I'd like to ask for some advice on how to handle them. My main concern is to avoid duplication, so ideally they should stay in a single place, and be used by both apps.

First I tried was to add files from one project to the other as linked files. While this works for code file (they get built into the project they are linked to), it doesn't for aspx / ascx or css / javascript / images. It does if I publish first (if marked as content, they get copied during publish), but I can't do this all the time during development, and such files are not found when app is debugged / run from source code (sincve, obvious the linked files are not actually available in app file tree, when one is looking for any of them.

Another thought was to create pre-build event, and in that to copy all shared files from a common location.
e.g. I create a project Common and put there all files that are shared between applications, organized on folders, and on pre-build I perform an `xcopy`.

And another thoughts is to make all shared files part of a SVN repository which I reference with `svn:external`, in both projects.

But all looks to my little cumbersome. Does anyone had similar situation? How did you handled it?

Any advice on any of my suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have, at least, two options :

- sharing through virtual directories : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13724316/1236044
- create user control libraries : https://stackoverflow.com/a/640526/1236044

The virtual directories approach seems straightforward for ressources like css, js, images.
I also tend to like it for sharing user controls.

The library approach should need more work, but would ensure better reusability of the controls on the long run.

Comment: The first suggestion seems the best for my scenario (since I don't need user controls to be reusable, they are not meant to). But I have two issues: 1. can it be made to work with IIS Express? 2. it seems I have to change all paths referring all my images, CSS and scripts to point to virtual directory; not an easy task, giving the fact that the application have a few hundred pages.

Comment: @bzamfir for question 1, I must say I don't know. For question 2, it depends on your organization. If your ressource are in a small number of locations, /images or /css could be made virtual without having to change the paths in your pages.

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical problem this week with css and javascript files triplicated across three legacy projects.

I removed the files from two of the projects and replaced them with linked files to the first project, but when I ran the website I got 404 errors for css & javascript files missing in the pages belonging to the two projects.

So I simply added the nuget package ['MSBuild.WebApplication.CopyContentLinkedFiles'](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.WebApplication.CopyContentLinkedFiles/) to my solution and everything worked fine - the css and javascript files were deployed fine for the two projects and my 404 errors disappeared.

I didn't have any shared .aspx / .ascx files, but I would imagine it will work for them too.

See also this [question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166975/add-as-link-for-javascript-files-returning-404-in-debug).